# how to show Completion Status of form in php

Tags: php, ajax

actually i want to show **"Completion Status"** in my website sign up form..but don't have have a idea how to put this...

I want to add Completion Status just like this link...

```
    Visit http://www.magicbricks.com/post-property-for-sale-rent/residential-commercial
```

In this link....as we complete form...completion status increses.....I want to do like this....

But i don't have any idea....anyone can suggest me regarding this....or provide link of any type of example..

Thanks...

Comment: in your ajax success method display a message of completion or image what you want you can do after success or completion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you try ready script.
   It's preety easy to implement it.
    progressbar depend on your form field.

I have two demo link try it out.

```
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-progress-bar/
http://css-tricks.com/display-form/
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example would be useful to your requirement,

[Form complete percentage plug-in](http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/266_progressSlider/jQuery%20UI/regForm.html)